# How do I convert a 1D array to a 3D array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file composed of 4096 (16^3) bytes that I need to load up and throw into a 3D array. Each byte represents a tile ID in a 16^3 chunk, so how can I create a 3D array based off a 1D array with 16 length, width and depth? I know the algorithm is something like this:

```
i = x + WIDTH * (y + HEIGHT * z);


z = Math.round(i / (WIDTH * HEIGHT));
y = Math.round((i - z * WIDTH * HEIGHT) / WIDTH);
x = i - WIDTH * (y + HEIGHT * z);
```

How do I find i though? I don't understand, considering i is a variable in calculating the x, y, and z variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with three nested loops. Use the first formula that you give to go from a set of `x`, `y`, and `z` to the corresponding index in the 1D array, like this:

```
byte[] data = ... // Read 4096 bytes
byte[][][] res = new byte[16][16][16];
for (int x = 0 ; x != 16 ; x++) {
    for (int y = 0 ; y != 16 ; y++) {
        for (int z = 0 ; z != 16 ; z++) {
            res[x][y][z] = data[16*16*x + 16*y + z];
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the way your data is organized (e.g. by layer, then by row, than by column, or by column, then by layer, then by row, or by row, then by column, then by layer, etc.) you might need to switch the order of `x`, `y`, and `z` in the computation of the index into the `data` array.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    byte[][][] a = new byte[16][16][16];
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file");
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            is.read(a[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: How does that work though? Is that called a jagged array? I don't entirely understand how that works!

Comment: [][][] means 3-D array see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: No, I understand that. But the last line in the for loop is.read(a[i][j]), you only use two dimensions when you created a 3D array. Why is that?

Comment: because a[i][j] is the actual array  byte[16] so InputStream uses read into array read(byte[])

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that is more beneficial than the answer I accepted (not to mention I really don't think I get it...) I just don't get how you can have a 3D array and only use 2 dimensions.